# HP Mini: Switching fan off in the BIOS

Tags: power-management, fan, cooling

I have just bought a HP Mini 210.

I was going though the BIOS setting and I noticed there is a option to enable FAN ON all the time.

I was thinking "do I need the fan on all the time?"

Would disabling this would it over heat the CPU? Or would the fan come on when its needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the fans are often not accessible via ACPI.  In these cases, thee BIOS retains control of the fans.  It will regulate the fan speed as needed.  There are utilities which will display the resources available to ACPI.  This will indicate whether the fan is controllable.  Even when the fan is not available, the temperature usually is so you can install a temperature monitor to see what is happening.  CPU should warm up and kick in the fan if you run anything CPU intensive.  Also check the CPU speed, as this usually is slower under low load and higher under higher load.  Higher CPU speeds generate more heat.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't overheat if the OS you are using implements the acpi functionality properly.  I do like that it is available in the bios in case you need to disable acpi for some reason.

Comment: I am currently running Fedora 14 xfce. So I am not too sure about the acpi. How could I find out? Thanks.

Comment: FC14 should implement it out of the box...I am not a fedora user but this should work: http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/validation.php

Comment: these fellows claim it is enabled out of the box: http://www.columbia.edu/~ariel/acpi/acpi_howto.txt

Comment: i am currently using an hp pavilion dv7 and at least on this platform hp exposes fan controls to acpi

Answer (score 1):

be sure that ACPI thermal zone support is built as a module in your kernel, then make sure that module is loaded:

`modprobe thermal` usually does the trick.. fans will operate correctly.